# Is YouTube IFrame API already loaded

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I want to know if the API has already been loaded. I can't find anything about it here:

> YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Is there anyone here who knows how to find out? (There is a global variable YT, but that does not seem to be an official way to check it.)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the documentation, but looking at the code this is what is used:

```js
window["YT"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am using undocumented solution to check if onYouTubeIframeAPIReady was reached:

```js
if (typeof YT !== 'undefined' && YT.loaded) {
    //API is ready
}
```